# How to pass javascript variable to script embed tag

Tags: javascript

I have a script which I am struggling with:

It does two things

1. Takes the variable parameter from a URL
2. Adds the parameter as a variable in a script embed tag

Number one works and I have been testing it with an iframe and I am able to pass the variable as the source code.

Number two does not work for script tags 
here is a snippet of the code

Heres the code I have to collect the variable from the url

```
// Parse the URL parameter
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
   name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g,"\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the parameter a variable name



var myvariable = getParameterByName('variable');

 $('#myvariable').html(myvariable);
```

I now want to pass myvariable to the javascript

```
<div id="otEmbedContainer" style="width:800px; height:640px"></div> <script src="https://exmaple.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=number&variable=myvariable"></script>
```

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Amended code doesnt seem to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Parse the URL parameter
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
   name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g,"\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the parameter a variable name



var myvariable = getParameterByName('variable');
```

$('#myvariable').html(variable);

function addScript( src, value ) {
    var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
    s.setAttribute( 'src', 'https://exmaple.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=number&variable=' );
    s.setAttribute( 'myvalue', myId);
    document.body.appendChild( s );
}

addScript("s");

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you are referring to as an example.

Comment: You could look at the Location href member this will give you the URI then you have to extract it yourself.

Comment: The script will be unaware of the Url used to include it in the page.  If you try to access any location information it will return page location instead.  This is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and it sounds like you actually just want to access variables in one script that were previously created in another.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hi my apologies I am new to this and now I have added an example of the code, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the values from the URL, but if the value is defined, you can pass it to your javascript using the attribute

```
<div id="otEmbedContainer" style="width:800px; height:640px"></div> 
<script src="https://exmaple.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=number" myvalue="1234"></script>
```

And then in your javascript, you can get the value using:

```
document.currentScript.getAttribute('myvalue'); //1234
```

**Update**

Now, when you are retrieving the value at runtime from the URL, you need to dynamically load the JS too.
Remove the script from your HTML, once you have the value from your URL, then create a script and add it to HTML

```
function addScript( src, value ) {
    var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
    s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
    s.setAttribute( 'myvalue', value);
    document.body.appendChild( s );
}
```

Call the function given above with your source link and the value which you need to pass to JS.

**Example:**

Your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic JS example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="load();">Load JS and show value from URL</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var load = function(){
            var url = new URL(window.location.href);
            var value = url.searchParams.get("value");

            var s = document.createElement("script")
            s.setAttribute("src", "./test.js");
            s.setAttribute("value", value);
            document.body.appendChild(s);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Your JS

```
value = document.currentScript.getAttribute('value');
alert(value);
```

Load the HTML in the browser, pass the value in URL `?value=yeah` and click on the button to see the magic.

Comment: Hi Tejashwi Thank you for the answer, I have included the full code above would this answer still apply?

Comment: Hi Tejashwi Thank you I made the amendments to the code but doesnt seem to work

Comment: @bobjones without seeing what you've done, I can't help. If possible update your post with recent code changes that you've done

Comment: @bobjones I can't see from where you are calling the function `addScript`. Just copy the function which I posted below your `getParameterByName` function, and then call the function after this line `var myvariable = getParameterByName('variable');` Call it like `addScript('https://exmaple.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=number&variable=', myvariable);`

Comment: Hi Tejashwi thanks again but I tried the code and still not working here is what I used https://jsfiddle.net/jonesb78/r6wtu0ob/1/

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to read the parameter from within the same script, you can get the last script tag and read the src from it.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];

function parseQueryString(src) {
    var query = src.split('?').pop();
    var params = query.split('&');
    var result = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var parts = params[i].split('=');
        result[decodeURIComponent(parts[0])] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(parseQueryString(lastScript.src))
```